# Ставим запятую?

Tags: пунктуация

*...а именно последовательность действий(,) составляющих процесс с указанием ответственных лиц.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположительно, здесь надо ставить две запятые: *...а именно последовательность действий, **составляющих процесс**, с указанием ответственных лиц.*